# Parsing out data using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to use BeautifulSoup to parse through a DOM tree and extract the names of authors. Below is a snippet of HTML to show the structure of the code I'm going to scrape.

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="list-authors">
<span class="descriptor">Authors:</span> 
<a href="/find/astro-ph/1/au:+Lin_D/0/1/0/all/0/1">Dacheng Lin</a>, 
<a href="/find/astro-ph/1/au:+Remillard_R/0/1/0/all/0/1">Ronald A. Remillard</a>, 
<a href="/find/astro-ph/1/au:+Homan_J/0/1/0/all/0/1">Jeroen Homan</a> 
</div>
<div class="list-authors">
<span class="descriptor">Authors:</span> 
<a href="/find/astro-ph/1/au:+Kosovichev_A/0/1/0/all/0/1">A.G. Kosovichev</a>
</div>

<!--There are many other div tags with this structure-->
</body>
</html>
```

My point of confusion is that when I do soup.find, it finds the first occurrence of the div tag that I'm searching for. After that, I search for all 'a' link tags. At this stage, how do I extract the authors names from each of the link tags and print them out? Is there a way to do it using BeautifulSoup or do I need to use Regex? How do I continue iterating over every other other div tag and extract the authors names?

```
import re
import urllib2,sys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
html = urllib2.urlopen(address).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    try:

        authordiv = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'list-authors'})
        links=tds.findAll('a')


        for link in links:
            print ''.join(link[0].contents)

        #Iterate through entire page and print authors


    except IOError: 
        print 'IO error'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

just use findAll for the divs link you do for the links

for authordiv in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'list-authors'}):

Answer (score 1):

Since `link` is already taken from an iterable, you don't need to subindex `link` -- you can just do `link.contents[0]`.

`print link.contents[0]` with your new example with two separate `<div class="list-authors">` yields:

```
Dacheng Lin
Ronald A. Remillard
Jeroen Homan
A.G. Kosovichev
```

So I'm not sure I understand the comment about searching other divs.  If they are different classes, you will either need to do a separate `soup.find` and `soup.findAll`, or just modify your first `soup.find`.

Comment: And if there are more div tags, how do I iterate over those ones?

Comment: If you search by CSS class you then get a list of elements and you can iterate with a for loop (see: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class). Do something like: `authordiv = soup.find('div', class_ = 'list-authors')`.