# How to use Python to get data using Web Scraping

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I want to get data from this website: http://transparencia.petrobras.com.br/licitacoes-contratos/contratos
From a time interval

The page returns a table and the option to export as Excel or CSV, but there is a lot of data and the export option dont really works depending on the size of the data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36y2D.png)

How can a get the content of this table ?

Comment: Have you tried modules such as [BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501690/parsing-out-data-using-beautifulsoup-in-python)?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately this is not a code-writing or tutorial service, and we ask that you provide a [mcve] including _code_ for what you've already tried based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts

Comment: I am a beginner in coding...

I have seen some tutorials on Beautiful Soup, but Url of this  website dosen't change when i serach dor a result( the url is always the same). It shows tha use __DoPostback

so i can find the div and ids of the table.

I don't know if i am doing something wrong or is just the website that dosen't alowed this kind operation